# Requesting timing out when connecting to SAS webservice from PHP

Tags: php, web-services, sas, soap-client

**Problem**

I'm trying to connect a PHP script to a SAS web service (SAS Stored Process Web Application).
The script always gives timeout, although I have tried to change the socket time out and SOAPClient timeout values.
The SAS Web Service responds promptly and correctly when executed from the SoapUI client.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://laptop-ht08lb7f/SASBIWS/services/Test13?WSDL";

$client = new SoapClient($url, array("trace" => 1, "debug" => 1, "exceptions" => 0));

$params = array(
  "Credit_Amount" => 1.0,
  "Dur_Credit" => 1.0,
  "Foreign_Worker" => 1.0,
  "Instalment" => 1.0,
  "MostVal_Asset" => 1.0,
  "Num_Years" => 1.0,
  "PayStat_Previous" => 1.0,
  "Savings_Stocks" => 1.0,
  "Telephone" => 1.0,
  "Acct_Balance" => 1.0
);

$response = $client->storedProcessforCustomerScoring(array($params));
print_r($response);

?>
```

**Debug**

Since the request times out, I am unable to the see the result of

```
$client->__getLastRequestHeaders()
$client->__getLastRequest()
```

As such I do not know if the Request is created correctly.

**Experiments**

I tried the following to get the functions and types from the WebService:

```
<?php
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions()); 
    var_dump($client->__getTypes());
?>
```

And got this result:

For functions:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(116) "storedProcessforCustomerScoringResponse storedProcessforCustomerScoring(storedProcessforCustomerScoring $parameters)"
}
```

For types:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(97) "struct storedProcessforCustomerScoring {
 storedProcessforCustomerScoringParameters parameters;
}"
  [1]=>
  string(272) "struct storedProcessforCustomerScoringParameters {
 double Credit_Amount;
 double Dur_Credit;
 double Foreign_Worker;
 double Instalment;
 double MostVal_Asset;
 double Num_Years;
 double PayStat_Previous;
 double Savings_Stocks;
 double Telephone;
 double Acct_Balance;
}"
  [2]=>
  string(128) "struct storedProcessforCustomerScoringResponse {
 storedProcessforCustomerScoringResult storedProcessforCustomerScoringResult;
}"
  [3]=>
  string(66) "struct storedProcessforCustomerScoringResult {
 Streams Streams;
}"
  [4]=>
  string(36) "struct Streams {
 _WEBOUT _WEBOUT;
}"
  [5]=>
  string(60) "struct _WEBOUT {
 base64Binary Value;
 string contentType;
}"
}
```

**SoapUI**

Here is the XML Request when it is done by SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tes="http://tempuri.org/Test13">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tes:storedProcessforCustomerScoring>
         <tes:parameters>
            <tes:Credit_Amount>250</tes:Credit_Amount>
            <tes:Dur_Credit>1</tes:Dur_Credit>
            <tes:Foreign_Worker>1</tes:Foreign_Worker>
            <tes:Instalment>1</tes:Instalment>
            <tes:MostVal_Asset>1</tes:MostVal_Asset>
            <tes:Num_Years>1</tes:Num_Years>
            <tes:PayStat_Previous>1</tes:PayStat_Previous>
            <tes:Savings_Stocks>1</tes:Savings_Stocks>
            <tes:Telephone>1</tes:Telephone>
            <tes:Acct_Balance>1</tes:Acct_Balance>
         </tes:parameters>
      </tes:storedProcessforCustomerScoring>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Can someone give me some tips to debug this or to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: requests are normally served via a url with path `/SASStoredProcess` and an STP identified with an `_PROGRAM` parameter.  May I ask what kind of service you are requesting?  Which version of SAS?

Comment: This is not the SASStoredProcess Web application.  it is the BI Web Services application.  You should clarify that in your question.

Comment: The type of service is XMLA and the SAS version is 9.4

Answer (score 0):

Check your url

I think this

```
$url = "http://laptop-ht08lb7f/SASBIWS/services/Test13?WSDL";
```

Should be this

```
$url = "http://laptop-ht08lb7f/SASBIWS/services/Test13";
```

What URL is SOAPUI sending?

Also, try capturing the traffic with something like Fiddler to compare the two calls.

Comment: SOAPUI sends "http://laptop-ht08lb7f/SASBIWS/services/Test13" but when use in the code also does not work